# I know how to remove vowels from a String,but how do I remove certain spaces from a string

Tags: java, formatting, whitespace, replaceall, removing-whitespace

The code bellow removes the vowels form the string but it does not remove the spaces that corresponds before or after the "_".

```
public static String removeVowels(String str) {
    str = str.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]",""); 


    return str;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("__" + removeVowels(" The Lion king ") + "__");

}
}
```

Console Output:

```
__ Th Ln kng __
```

What the console output should be:

```
__Th Ln kng__
```

Not really sure how I would go about doing this without going into the main method and manually removing the spaces.

Comment: You're question title is "removing spaces from a string" -- but it sounds like you want a much more specific case - of removing spaces after the first two `_` and before the last two `_`?. From your code it looks like you've created the bug in your test cases: `" Snowboarding school "` has a leading and a trailing space...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking, but perhaps you want to `trim()` your String. This removes white space from the front and back ends of the String:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]","").trim();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking to do. Wow so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\s*__\s*","");
```